# Какие доп. характеристики объекта "house" возможно получить через API Яндекс.Карт?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Какие из перечисленных характеристик объекта "house", можно получить через API Яндекс.Карт?

1. Установить тип объекта:

- жилой многоквартирный дом
- частное домовладение

2. Установить этажность объекта
3. Установить кол-во квартир для объекта с типом "жилой многоквартирный дом"

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Геокодер Яндекс предназначен для получения адреса из координат и наоборот. В его задачи не входит передача пользователям всей информации по объектам, что есть в компании. Интересующие вас детали API Яндекс не отдают. Формат ответа геокодера есть в [справке сервиса](https://yandex.ru/dev/geocode/doc/ru/response).